# How to join multiple queryDSL tables

Tags: spring, jpa, spring-data, dsl, querydsl

I have some tables and I want to get result using queryDSL join, but haven't found any examples on multiple joins using queryDSL.

I have these tables:

- Account table: accountId (PK) | email | password
- account_profile table: accountId (PK)(fk to account) | nickname
- Community table: articleId (PK) | accountId (fk to account) | title | content

Now I want below JPQL to be queryDSL code

```
select r from community r join r.account.profile a where a.nickname = :nickname
```

I have entity metamodels - QAccount, QAccountProfile, QCommunity

Additionally, I have to get the result with pagination, so the query should be called with `pageable` object.

Here is my work that doesn't work yet.

```
JPAQuery</*What generic type expected?*/> query = new JPAQuery</*???*/>(entityManager);
Predicate predicate = query.from(QCommunity.community).join(/*join directly accountProfile? or account? is it QEntity or real entity?*/);

// where should I place nickname matching condition ?


...

list = (repository.findAll(predicate, pageable)).getContent();
```

Where should I place the nickname matching condition?

**EDIT: Appended entity information**

**Account.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="account", uniqueConstraints={
    @UniqueConstraint(columnNames="account_seq"),
    @UniqueConstraint(columnNames="email")
})
@DynamicInsert
@DynamicUpdate
@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode
@ToString(includeFieldNames=true)
@RequiredArgsConstructor(staticName="of")
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Account implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="account_seq", nullable=false, unique=true)
    private Integer accountId;

    @Column(name="email", nullable=false, unique=true)
    @NonNull
    private String email;

    @NonNull
    private String password;

    @OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy="account")
    private AccountProfile profile;

    @OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy="account")
    private AccountSecurity security;
}
```

**AccountProfile.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="account_profile", uniqueConstraints={
    @UniqueConstraint(columnNames={"account_seq"}),
    @UniqueConstraint(columnNames={"nickname"})
})
@DynamicInsert
@DynamicUpdate
@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode
@ToString(includeFieldNames=true)
@RequiredArgsConstructor(staticName="of")
@NoArgsConstructor
public class AccountProfile implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name="account_seq", referencedColumnName="account_seq")
    private Account account;

    @Column(name="nickname", nullable=false)
    @NonNull
    private String nickname;

}
```

**Community.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="community", uniqueConstraints = {
        @UniqueConstraint(columnNames="article_seq")
})
@DynamicInsert
@DynamicUpdate
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode
@ToString(includeFieldNames=true)
public class Community {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="article_seq", nullable=false, unique=true)
    private Long articleId;

    @ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name="account_seq", referencedColumnName="account_seq")
    private Account account;

    @Column(name="title", nullable=false)
    private String title;

    @Column(name="content", nullable=false)
    private String content;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name="reg_dt")
    private Date date;

    @Column(name="read_cnt", nullable=false)
    private int readCount;

    @Column(name="attach_url")
    private String attachUrl;

    @Column(name="attach_filename")
    private String attachFileName;

    @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy="article")
    private Set<CommunityReply> replies;
}
```

**EDIT: PROBLEM SOLVED**

To help others who is facing the problem like me, I am gonna post my working code. the code is searching any community articles with matching specific nickname.

```
@PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;


    private List<Community> getList(int pageNo, String keyword, int rowsOnPage){

        int offset = (pageNo -1) * rowsOnPage;
        int limit = rowsOnPage;

        JPAQuery<Community> query = new JPAQuery<Community>(entityManager);

        QCommunity qCommunity = QCommunity.community;
        QAccount qAccount = QAccount.account;
        QAccountProfile qAccountProfile = QAccountProfile.accountProfile;

        return query
            .from(qCommunity)
            .innerJoin(qCommunity.account ,qAccount)
            .innerJoin(qAccount.profile, qAccountProfile)
            .where(qAccountProfile.nickname.like("%"+keyword+"%"))
            .orderBy(qCommunity.articleId.desc())
            .offset(offset)
            .limit(limit)
        .fetch();
    }
```

Comment: Please post code for the Entities.

Comment: @Mogsdad thank you for re-arranging my question :)

Comment: @lzagkaretos Updated my entity information thank you :)

Comment: Is query `select r from article r join r.account.profile a where a.nickname = :nickname` correct? I mean, you have not provided code for `Article` entity and how it is connected with the others.

Comment: i am so sorry article is wrong, "select r from community ..." is right, I will edit this post.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

First of all, declare a custom extended base repository class for QueryDSL queries.

First the interface:

```
@NoRepositoryBean
public interface ExtendedQueryDslJpaRepository<T, ID extends Serializable> 
        extends JpaRepository<T, ID>, QueryDslPredicateExecutor<T> {

    <T1> Page<T1> findAll(JPQLQuery jpqlQuery, Pageable pageable);
}
```

And then the implementation:

```
public class ExtendedQueryDslJpaRepositoryImpl<T, ID extends Serializable>
        extends QueryDslJpaRepository<T, ID> implements ExtendedQueryDslJpaRepository<T, ID> {

    private static final EntityPathResolver DEFAULT_ENTITY_PATH_RESOLVER = SimpleEntityPathResolver.INSTANCE;

    private final EntityPath<T> path;
    private final PathBuilder<T> builder;
    private final Querydsl querydsl;

    private EntityManager entityManager;

    public ExtendedQueryDslJpaRepositoryImpl(JpaEntityInformation<T, ID> entityInformation, EntityManager entityManager) {
        this(entityInformation, entityManager, DEFAULT_ENTITY_PATH_RESOLVER);
    }

    public ExtendedQueryDslJpaRepositoryImpl(JpaEntityInformation<T, ID> entityInformation, 
           EntityManager entityManager, EntityPathResolver resolver) {

        super(entityInformation, entityManager);
        this.path = resolver.createPath(entityInformation.getJavaType());
        this.builder = new PathBuilder(this.path.getType(), this.path.getMetadata());
        this.querydsl = new Querydsl(entityManager, this.builder);
        this.entityManager = entityManager;
    }

    @Override
    public <T1> Page<T1> findAll(JPQLQuery jpqlQuery, Pageable pageable) {

        // Count query
        final JPQLQuery<?> countQuery = jpqlQuery;

        // Apply pagination
        JPQLQuery<T1> query = querydsl.applyPagination(pageable, jpqlQuery);

        // Run query
        return PageableExecutionUtils.getPage(query.fetch(), pageable, countQuery::fetchCount);
    }
}
```

Define the new class as base for base and repositories in a `@Configuration` class.

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackageClasses = ..., repositoryBaseClass = ExtendedQueryDslJpaRepositoryImpl.class)
```

Your repositories then should extend from the new interface (which of course extends JpaRepository):

```
@Repository
public interface CommunityRepository extends ExtendedQueryDslJpaRepository<Community, Long> {
}
```

Then, you can try the following code:

```
String nickname = "nick";

QAccount account = QAccount.account;
QAccountProfile accountProfile = QAccountProfile.accountProfile;
QCommunity community = QCommunity.community;

JPQLQuery query = new JPAQuery(entityManager);

BooleanBuilder predicate = new BooleanBuilder();
predicate.and(accountProfile.nickname.eq(nickname));

// select r from community r join r.account.profile a where a.nickname = :nickname
query.from(community)
     .join(community.account, account)
     .join(account.accountProfile, accountProfile)
     .where(predicate);

repository.findAll(query, pageable);
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you  and can i ask you where shold i refer on this problem?  I mean  there is no reference link on google

Comment: Did it worked for you? Documentation about using QueryDSL exists [here](http://www.querydsl.com/static/querydsl/latest/reference/html/ch02s03.html).

Comment: Actually i didnt try yet  after editing my post .I was about to sleep. In my country the  time is 4 00 am

Comment: Hi, I am late, can I ask you something? I followed your query but there's warning on initializing JPQLQuery object, pointing out that this object doesn't have generic type, so I want to have it generic type, then what should be the type? is it Community? or QCommunity? By the way, is there a link to reference ?

Comment: It should be of objects return type. So `Community`.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response, and having following your query, it seems have another error on "repository.findAll(query, pageable)", with error "The method findAll(Predicate, Pageable) in the type QueryDslPredicateExecutor<Community> is not applicable for the arguments (JPQLQuery, Pageable)", And you don't need to response quickly I have lots of time.

Comment: I found a document http://www.querydsl.com/static/querydsl/4.0.1/reference/html_single/ now I'm about to read that link and i'm gonna solve myself thank you :), I don't want to disturb you by adding replies, anyway thanks for your help :)

Comment: May I ask which versions of Spring and QueryDSL are you using? I am going to add code for a custom base repository, which will solve such problems, and then you would be able to use querydsl as you wish.

Comment: I am using spring boot 1.5.8.RELEASE, and QueryDSL 4.1.4

Comment: Thank you really, I finally solved this issue, I have modified my post.

Comment: Glad to here. I have already post my code I told you. If you wish, give it a try sometime. Have a nice day. (May I ask for a vote up? :))

Comment: does entityPathResolver and entityInformation be injected automatically? anyway, i like the style of defining @NoRepositoryBean and implement that interface, because it encapsulates pagination code. thank you

Comment: Yes they are. :) I like it too, and we are using it extensively.

Comment: `QueryDslJpaRepository` is now deprecated, is there a way to provide custom implementation to `QuerydslPredicateExecutor` without overriding whole `JpaRepository`?

Comment: So in order to use JOIN, it is needed to rewrite the repositories. That seems like a lot of work. The more I work with querydsl the more doubts I have.

Comment: @ManolisPap I haven't used `QueryDsl` the last couple of years, so I am not aware whether a better (more straightforward way) exists.

Comment: @lzagkaretos Your solution is perfect. I just wanted to note that querydsl at times make things like that too difficult and hacky solutions are needed.

Answer (score 4):

I found one solution as

```
QEntity qEntity1 = new QEntity("qEntity1");
QEntity qEntity2 = new QEntity("qEntity2");
```

so while querying you can use

```
new JPAQueryFactory(entityManager).from(qSampleBO)
    .innerJoin(qEntity1).on(qEntity1.id.eq(qSampleBO.address.id))
    .innerJoin(qEntity2).on(qEntity2.id.eq(qSampleBO.secondary_address.id))
    ...
```