# QueryDSL join on multiple fields

Tags: querydsl

I have some entities in my normalized schema

```
@Entity
public class Dual {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
  private Long id;
  @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  private Member member1;
  @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  private Member member2;
  ...
}

@Entity
public class Member {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
  private Long id;
  private String name;
  @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  private Address address;
  ...
}

@Entity
public class Address {
   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
   private Long id;
   private String zip;
   ...
}
```

And now the use case is to select all `Dual` entities which contain at least one member with an address having a specific zip.

In pure SQL this would mean something like

```
SELECT * from DUAL d 
INNER JOIN MEMBER m on (d.member1 = m.id OR d.member2 = m.id)
INNER JOIN ADDRESS a on m.address = a.id
WHERE a.zip = '12345'
```

Is there any chance to express this wit QueryDSL 4.1.3?

What I've got so far according to the docs is

```
final String zip = "12345";
final QDual qdual = QDual.dual;
final JPAQuery<Dual> dualQuery = new JPAQuery<>(em)
            .select(qdual)
            .from(qdual)
            .where(qdual.member1.address.zip.eq(zip)
               .or(qdual.member2.address.zip.eq(zip)
             ));
```

This generates a rather imperformant cross-join query

```
select dual0_.id as id1_160_, 
       dual0_.member1_id as member2_160_, 
       dual0_.member2_id as member3_160_ 
from Dual dual0_ cross join 
     Member member1_ cross join 
     Address address2_ cross join 
     Member member3_ cross join 
     Address address4_ 
where dual0_.member1_id=member1_.id and 
      member1_.address_id=address2_.id and 
      dual0_.member2_id=member3_.id and 
      member3_.address_id=address4_.id and 
      (address2_.zip=? or address4_.zip=?)
```

Having played around a little bit with explain plans it seems to me that in this case an UNION select would be the most performant way.

Comment: It should be no problem,that's possible straight out of the documentation. Where have you got to and what's not working?

Comment: Updated original question with current results.

Comment: I think this question shows how to do what you want https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47701172/how-to-join-multiple-querydsl-tables?rq=1